# - Who doesn't like me? - Everyone! / No one!

Tags: questions, multiple-negation

Consider this exchange between two people that I saw on TV: A has told B that none of B's colleagues like B. B comes back with a question and gets an answer:

> B: *Who doesn't like me?*
>   A: *Everyone!*

Why did A say *everyone*? Should A not have said *no one* instead? Is it not the same as the choice between these sentences? :

> *Everyone doesn't like you.*
>   *No one likes you.*

Interestingly enough, I found 48 hits for "*everyone doesn't*" in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), for instance:

- *Everyone does n't care.*
  <sub>(If it were me, I would've said *Not everyone cares* or *No one cares*, depending on what I'd meant to say.)</sub>
- *Everyone doesn't have that luxury of another room.*
  <sup>(...)</sup>
- *Tell me again why everyone doesn't just network into this meeting?*
  <sup>(...)</sup>

Now, what's the story here? Are both options possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how the results in COCA are related to the response to the question *Who doesn't like me?*. In any case, *Everyone doesn't do that* and *Not everyone does that* are not the same. *Everyone doesn't do that* implies "nobody does that", while *Not everyone does that* implies "some may do that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of the difficulty that English has in dealing with negative sentences.  In this case, the question

> Who doesn't like me?

is asking us to identify the group of people who dislike the questioner.  As you suggest

> No one likes you.

would probably be the clearest answer, but the difficulty is that a single word response of *nobody* doesn't work.  Here that would mean that

> Nobody doesn't like you. (So everyone must like you.)

It's clumsy to say

> Everyone doesn't like you.

and that's not something you'd hear in normal conversation, except as an intentionally awkward construction used to mock the person asking the question.  It is best avoided in anything remotely formal and honestly in informal conversation as well.  Especially for a person learning English, the assumption would likely be that you had made a mistake rather than that you were being clever.

That said, there is one case in which *Everybody doesn't* and *nobody doesn't* have become famous as part of [an advertisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sara_Lee_Corporation):

> "Everybody doesn't like something, but nobody doesn't like Sara Lee."
>   Later shortened to a jingle, "Nobody doesn't like Sara Lee."

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. Do you find the short answer (_Everyone!_) here  clumsy too?

Comment: And I assume that the advertisement means _Although it's not true that everyone likes Sara Lee, but there's no one who dislikes it either_; am I right?

Comment: What do you think of *anyone* as a response?

Comment: @snailboat Honestly, I think it runs into the same sort of problem as "everyone."  If you try to build a sentence with it, it just doesn't work properly.

Comment: @MJF I think that the meaning is more along the lines of "Everyone has dislikes, but nobody dislikes Sara Lee."